# how to append item to an array value with Sequelize + PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, promise, append, sequelize.js

I have a posgresql database, table has a column which is an array: `Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.BIGINT)`.

What is the right way to append a new item to the array?

I am new to posgresql, sequelize and nodejs. May be it is a trivial question.
From reading around I think I know how to use Promise.all to read all rows, append, and update back.
The question, isn't there any useful shortcut.

[PostreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) mentions a function `array_append(anyarray, anyelement)`.

[Sequelize documentation offers](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-fn) a function fn, which `Creates an object representing a database function`, but only seems to be working in `where and order parts`

Any way to combine those for an append-like update?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Array Datatype has many methods like append, concat etc. which you can see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html). I will give an example with `array_append` function.

`Room` is a sequelize model and `job_ids` is a column in this model with datatype as Array of integer. `sequelize` is an instant of Sequelize class.

```
Room.update(
 {'job_ids': sequelize.fn('array_append', sequelize.col('job_ids'), new_jobId)},
 {'where': {'id': roomId}}
);
```

Assuming default value of this column is an empty array else it may throw an error.